# organization of helper methods

Tags: c#

I have some methods in a class which get called by only one method in the same class. Where is the best practice to put such methods? Private at the end of the class?
Comming from gcc's C implementation I would define those helper methods in the method they are needed for, but that doesn't seem to work in C#.

Comment: Can you post some example of your code please.

Comment: That seems like a decent strategy to me.

Comment: @AntP Just because it's only called by one method doesn't mean it's only called exactly once in that one method.  Also, it can be quite useful to break up an operation into multiple smaller operations; remember the single responsibility principle.  It makes it much easier to analyze and reason about a method when it's broken up into its logical components instead of having God methods that try to do everything.

Answer (score 1):

I often use Private methods at the end of the class, as you mention. But if those helper methods are closely related to the calling method, you could place them right after the calling method and surround it all in a `#region` to visually group them, as well as allow for expanding/collapsing as a unit in Visual Studio.

```
    #region Range Checking
    public void CheckRange(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
    {
        CheckRangeValue(lowerBound);
        CheckRangeValue(upperBound);
    }
    private void CheckRangeValue(int value)
    {
        //...
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: I never knew there was an end of a class...

Comment: Ctrl-End will usually get you there in VS! :-) Of course the compiler doesn't care, but they say to code like the programmer who'll maintain your code will have anger issues and know where you live. So for readability I try to organize my classes' code with properties and public methods up top and private methods near the bottom. Or grouped logically in `#region`s, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In Bob Martin's excellent book [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.com.br/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882), there is a chapter on vertical formatting, with a section titled "The Newspaper Metaphor". I'll post an excerpt (emphasis mine):

> Think of a well-written newspaper article. You read it vertically. At the top you expect a headline that will tell you what the story is about and allows you to decide whether it is something you want to read. The ﬁrst paragraph gives you a synopsis of the whole story, hiding all the details while giving you the broad-brush concepts. As you continue downward, the details increase until you have all the dates, names, quotes, claims, and other
>   minutia.
>
> **We would like a source ﬁle to be like a newspaper article**. The name should be simple but explanatory. The name, by itself, should be sufﬁcient to tell us whether we are in the right module or not. The topmost parts of the source ﬁle should provide the high-level concepts and algorithms.
>
> Detail should increase as we move downward, until at the end we ﬁnd the lowest level functions and details in the source ﬁle.

And a few pages ahead:

> **If one function calls another, they should be vertically close,
>   and the caller should be above the callee**, if at all possible. This gives the program a natural ﬂow. If the convention is followed reliably, readers will be able to trust that function deﬁnitions will follow shortly after their use.
>
> (...) [T]he topmost function calls those below it and (...) they in turn
>   call those below them. This makes it easy to ﬁnd the called functions and greatly enhances the readability of the whole module.

Besides this specific topic, the book contains a ton of other very, very useful well-funded information about these sometimes neglected aspects of code construction.